# CanCan and Devise, restricting login based on Role

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

I've just finished setting up Devise on a single application, using a single User model with two scopes, so I can have an `/admin/login` as well as a regular `/users/login` path. This works pretty well, my config/routes.rb file looks like this:

```
devise_for :users,
           :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout' }

devise_for :admins,
           :class_name => 'User',
           :skip => [:passwords, :registrations, :confirmations, :sessions],
           :controllers => { :sessions => 'admin/sessions' } do

  get 'admin/login' => 'admin/sessions#new', :as => :new_admin_session
  post 'admin/login' => 'admin/sessions#create', :as => :admin_session
  delete 'admin/logout' => 'admin/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_admin_session 
end
```

This works pretty fine and dandy, I can log in to each side of the application without affecting the other. That is, the session names are separate and logging into one does not log you into the other.

Now, I've set up CanCan with my `Roles` model, and an `Ability` model, and have these defined in my database and working.

Question is, I want to be able to fill out the form on `admin/login`, and receive an error message because my Role doesn't allow me to log into that area. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Somewhere your app is asking cancan for permission based on role.  Where do you have that?  If you are using a debugger, you can put a trace on the Ability model and then see the backtrace of who called it.  You have a filter somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your question.  If you are filling out the form on admin/login, then presumably you have not logged in yet?

If that's the case, then there is no current_user or current_admin and therefore nothing is passed to CanCan yet.

I have a similar set-up in my app and maintain different accounts on each side of the app.  My user account is different than my admin account.  If I forget and try to login to the admin side using my regular user account, I simply receive an unknown user/password error from Devise.